# Understanding CFSet and IOHIDDeviceRegisterRemovalCallback in IOKit

Tags: c, macos, core-foundation, iokit

I'm trying to understand a piece of code in the IOKit user space, written in C using CFSet, CFAllocator, and other non-NS*/Swift constructs.

https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-1445.40.1/hid.subproj/IOHIDDevice.c.auto.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2187/_index.html

Let's take `IOHIDDeviceRegisterRemovalCallback()` and `__IOHIDDeviceNotification()` as an example (the same goes for similar functions present, such as `IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputValueCallback` and `__IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback`.

IOHIDDeviceRegisterRemovalCallback() seems to register a callback in such a way that it will be able to handle multiple callbacks at once. This is because it's adding the `infoRef` into a `CFSet` called `removalCallbackSet`. Then __IOHIDDeviceNotification, which seems to be the single callback registered for the layer below this user-space code, it what gets called once and then it loops through removalCallbackSet and triggers each of the multiple registered callbacks.

However, in my second link, the documentation mentions that in order to 'unregister' a callback, you pass in null/nil to the register function. This doesn't make any sense. `infoRef` is now an instantiation of {callback=nil, context=nil} and removes that value from the CFSet. But that value will never have been in the set in the first place, because the set items would be of the form {callback=, context=}.

1) Am I missing something, or is the CFSetRemoveValue call effectively useless, and you can not actually remove callbacks from an IOHIDDeviceRef?

2) Am I correct in thinking that the CFSet is comparing the value of infoRef on the callback and context variables, and not the pointer to the infoRef itself?

3) Am I missing something with regard to how CFAllocator works?

4) Is the CFSet using only the value of `context`, and thus you unregister by passing the same context but a nil callback?

Answer (score 0):

"Number 4 is correct.

__IOHIDDeviceCallbackBaseDataIsEqual is how items in the set are compared to each other. It only checks the context.

result = info1->context == info2->context;"

https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/9jkaye/understanding_lowerlevel_cfset_and_an_iokit/e6sigfw/